# How to disable phone keyboard pop-up using Monaco Editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

On any device, I'd like to have the Monaco Editor as read-only and when using a mobile device and the user clicks into the editor, the mobile keyboard (iOS/Android) shouldn't pop-up. How to do that?

Setting `readOnly: true` doesn't prevent the keyboard to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `readOnly` with `domReadOnly` will completely prevent mobile keyboard.

```
editor.updateOptions({ readOnly: true, domReadOnly: true })
```

[MonacoEditorPlaygroundLink](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.45.0#XQAAAAJ-AQAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscwzjfRu_1uhs0-3YGTBOsVJ4S4FwfCDQb5-2uUHXTVAefbVSd9IzaZ_vv9VR9KugsKimARHSWlrTPOQHROITHxmAetfeRrm3VHdSe7_Etv6WpgzlH4vE8EOD3EPhJDl6tDpOO8RxKZbUytKns3T0NFFloo9Q21KsEBT298I6ZMwy651v2_CLa4BHJqW_nKOyMlMwnmMaj5CUPV2U_19FCL-YPplAAdEeXOp-6rYwhwNwpsWUTtgeQKhhzyomD3yKFN0wUt8iGVV0Kg4vmX9LgNIspuJZ5TEtnGm-ljxK1kwimqEnUpfjx9NzY_2dzMJf95MiwA)